# Can we use Shark 0.9.1 version with Spark 1.1.0?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, shark-sql

I know Shark has been subsumed by Spark SQL, a new module in Apache Spark. But my question is, can we use the existing Shark with new Spark versions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to its [release notes](https://github.com/amplab/shark/releases/tag/v0.9.1), Shark 0.9.1 only supports Spark 0.9.1.

[According to a mailing list post](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/incubator-spark-user/201406.mbox/%3CCAAswR-6W6enfcTsUOPbBewuWeW_Qc_FcUWk5MP4P7tXuAXtJoA@mail.gmail.com%3E), there is not an official version of Shark for Spark 1.0+.  Shark depends on non-public interfaces of Spark that have likely changed between 0.9.1 and 1.1.0, so it may be a significant amount of work to port Shark to Spark 1.0+.

Comment: Thanks Josh. We tried shark 0.9.1 with Spark 1.1.0, as you mentioned it shows some conflicts with logging. May be spark updated the logging jar versions.